# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Business-Intelligence SQL

Tags: oracle, business-intelligence, parentheses, ora-00907

Please see below SQL below in my BI for Oracle.  Please let me know how to fix this error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis.  I believe the issue is the If statement, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Any help is much appreciated. Thanks, Christine

```
SELECT 
    `(EWRPV.DEPARTMENT_NAME)  as DEPARTMENT_NAME, 
    (EWRPV.OPERATION_SEQ_NUM)  as OPERATION_SEQ_NUM, 
    (EWRPV.DATE_LAST_MOVED)  as DATE_LAST_MOVED, 
    (EWRPV.APPLIED_RESOURCE_UNITS)  as APPLIED_RESOURCE_UNITS, 
    (EWRPV.USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT)  as USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT, 
    (EWRPV.USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT * EWRPV.QUANTITY_COMPLETED)  as "Total Required Hours", 
    ((EWRPV.USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT * EWRPV.QUANTITY_COMPLETED) / EWRPV.APPLIED_RESOURCE_UNITS)  as "Efficiency %", 
    (EWRPV.PRIMARY_ITEM_NAME)  as PRIMARY_ITEM_NAME, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_COMPLETED)  as QUANTITY_COMPLETED, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_IN_QUEUE)  as QUANTITY_IN_QUEUE, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_REJECTED)  as QUANTITY_REJECTED, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_RUNNING)  as QUANTITY_RUNNING, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_SCRAPPED)  as QUANTITY_SCRAPPED, 
    (EWRPV.QUANTITY_WAITING_TO_MOVE)  as QUANTITY_WAITING_TO_MOVE, 
    (EWRPV.RESOURCE_NAME)  as RESOURCE_NAME, 
    (EWRPV.RESOURCE_UOM)  as RESOURCE_UOM, 
    (EWRPV.SCHEDULED_QUANTITY)  as SCHEDULED_QUANTITY, 
    (EWRPV.BASIS_TYPE)  as BASIS_TYPE, 
    (if((EWRPV.BASIS_TYPE="Lot",EWRPV.USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT/EWRPV.APPLIED_RESOURCE_UNITS,(EWRPV.USAGE_RATE_OR_AMOUNT*EWRPV.QUANTITY_COMPLETED)/ EWRPV.APPLIED_RESOURCE_UNITS)))  as "Efficiency of Lot Basis Type"
 FROM 
    
    XXEIS.EIS_WIP_RES_PERFOMANCE_V EWRPV
 WHERE 1=1 
    AND    EWRPV.RESOURCE_NAME IN ('LABOR- IND', 'LABOR-CNC', 'LABOR1', 'LABOR2', 'LABOR2-IND', 'SETUP-CNC', 'INSPECTOR1')   
    AND     EWRPV.DATE_LAST_MOVED  BETWEEN ( '11.30.2020') AND ( '12.01.2020' )'
```

Comment: `IF` is not valid in an SQL statement. Perhaps you meant `CASE`?

Comment: Also, double quotes are used to identify labels, not values. Use single quotes to identify values. I would also advise an explicit to_date or to_timestamp function to convert your values for date_last_moved to actual date or timestamp data types (whichever is appropriate) and not rely implicitly on the default date or timestamp format.

Comment: Case didn't work either.  I will keep working on it.  Thank you!